# Equivalent of lsmeans for proc qlim in SAS?

Tags: sas

I'm running a censored tobit model (continuous outcome ranging from 0 to 100, transformed from a proportion) in SAS and would like to obtain mean effects + 95% CIs across categories of an independent variable. Is there a command one can use to output that, similar to lsmeans / cl in proc glm? For reference, this is what my code looks like:

```
proc qlim data = mydata; 
class var1;
model outcomevar = var1;
endogenous outcomevar ~ censored (lb=0 ub=100); 
ods output parameterestimates=pe;
run;
```

Thank you!